# Documentation Missing for creating custom resource providers

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I would like to create my own resource provider, which will deploy a set of resources and configure them.. Is there some documentation on how this can be done? I believe the same is being used @MSFT for creating Databricks..

Comment: Not really sure, what you're asking ... you want to deploy some azure resources or provide a new resource type that will be deployed to the market place ?

Comment: I want to provide my own resource provider.. so that any user of azure can use it to deploy resources. just like how Microsoft is doing with Databricks or ACS

Comment: If you want to publish a service to the azure marketplace, check out this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace-publishing/marketplace-publishing-getting-started